# ABCPDF.Net AddText Control hyphenation

Tags: abcpdf, hyphenation

I'm using ABCPDF.net for generating PDF Pages. We've got a problem with the hyphenation system.

For example if we add a text with long words using

```
doc.AddText("This is a Verylongwordwhichdoesntfit");
```

and the Rect is too small, we get:

> this is a verylongwo
>   rdwhichdoesntfit.

My Question now is:
Can i control where it starts a new line. to have it break between long and word.
And can i tell it to use a - before the break like this?

> this is a verylongwo-
>   rdwhichdoesntfit.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Details in the documentation here:

http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/3-concepts/b-htmlstyles.htm

Comment: 1. He would have to use AddHtml instead of AddText for this to mean anything. 2. He would have to either specify specific lettters as breakable characters (like, "break after [aeiou]"), or edit the text to add soft hyphen characters to make hyphenation happen where he desires it.  3. Unless he edits text to add soft hyphens, the hyphen character isn't going to show, period.

Comment: 4. Link-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, with `.AddText()` there is no possibility of hyphenation at all. You'd have to switch to `.AddHtml()`.

Secondly, no, abcpdf has no intelligence about hyphenating at all; it can be told to break lines after certain characters (default is space), but it has no knowledge of English words or syllables.
See http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/3-concepts/b-htmlstyles.htm#stylerun (search for `canBreakAfter` at that link)

If you're able to edit your text, you can use soft hyphen characters

http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/3-concepts/b-htmlstyles.htm#stylerun, last line of the "Chars" section

> If you require fine control over hyphenation you can make use of the soft hyphen character – `&shy;`. This character is invisible and indicates a point at which a chunk of text may reasonably be broken.

For example, you'd use this command, and it might break at any of the places where the `&shy;` appears:

```
doc.AddHtml("This is a Very&shy;long&shy;word&shy;which&shy;doesnt&shy;fit");
```

But even this won't add the visible hyphens at the break, I don't think.